# Displaying repetition conditions for a cron command in a user friendly format

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cron

I want to display information about the conditions under which a selected command should be executed. I would like an elegant and easy way to do that, and I want to avoid using an external library if possible.

Comment: There is not per se a real frequecy: you can for instance set cron to run on all days of the month dividable by 13. Since months have a different amount of days, the frequency can vary.

Comment: Cron commands are more than frequency; they are about other conditions. Provided a more compact statement of the question.